# Создать Java Обновление программы

Tags: java, javafx, ftp

Всем привет. Скажите пожалуйста как сделать обновление программы JavaFX desktop?
Делать обновления с Ftp.
Если можно пример кода.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хм. Я конечно могу и ошибаться, но мне кажется единственный способ это сделать - создать отдельную программу, которая будет следить за вышедшими версиями с вашего сервера, удалять старый jar и выкачивать новый. А если в эту программу еще добавить возможность автоматически запускать приложение из jar при отсутсвии обновлений, то для конечного пользователя не будет видно что там на самом деле два приложения.

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант подходит возможно у вас есть пример кода?

Comment: Возможно Вас заинтересует мой проект, который я пока не завершил, но идея проста и понятна [UJACS](https://github.com/ezhov-da/ujacs/tree/dev) Там же можно ознакомиться с интересующим Вас подходом.